# Pandas でのデータ結合時にエラーが発生する

Tags: python, pandas

seriesに対し、日付をkeyにしてmerge_df1を左外部結合の下記のプログラムを実行するとエラーが発生するのですがなぜなのでしょうか？

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series(['1/1', '1/2', '1/3', '1/4', '1/5', '1/6','1/7',
                '1/8','1/9','1/10','1/11','1/12','1/13','1/14'],name='日付')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'日付':['1/1', '1/2', '1/3', '1/4', '1/6','1/7'],
                    '天気':['晴れ', '曇り', '晴れ', '曇り', '晴れ','曇り']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'日付':['1/8', '1/14', '1/9', '1/12', '1/11'],
                    '天気':['雨', '晴れ', '晴れ', '雨', '晴れ']})

# 2つのDataFrameを縦方向に連結
merge_df1 = np.concatenate([df1,df2],axis=0)  
print(f'連結：\n{merge_df1}\n')

# seriesに対し、日付をkeyにしてmerge_df1を左外部結合
merge_df2 = pd.merge(series,merge_df1,on='日付',how='left')
print(f'日付をkeyに左外部結合：\n{merge_df2}\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

まず、エラー文も載せるようにしましょう。

私の方で動かして出しました。

> Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'numpy.ndarray'> was passed

マージ出来るのはシリーズかデータフレームオブジェクトだけですが、numpy配列が渡されました。
という意味です。

つまりseriesかmerge_df1のどちらかがnumpy配列オブジェクトの可能性があります。
型をプリントしてみましょう。

print(type(series))
print(type(merge_df1))

> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

merge_df1がデータフレームではなくnumpy配列になっています。
私もここで気が付きましたが、np.concatenate()で結合しているのであたりまえですね。

このようにチェックして頂けたらと思います。
「pandas dataframe 結合」等で調べ直して見ましょう。

Comment: もしくは、今あるmerge_df1(numpy配列)をdataframeオブジェクトに変換するという手もあります。